# How to undo `rm -r *`?

Tags: file-recovery

I wanted to wipe all data on a USB device. Thing is, I accidentally mounted `/dev/sda1` instead of `/dev/sdb1` and accidentally deleted my Windows Recovery Partition.

I ran this from Ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas how to undo this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by sd**a**1 other than just meaning /dev/sda1.

Anyways, sorry to say that you're pretty much hosed if you're expecting things to return to normal. However, there *might* be some hope if what you care about recovering most is media files, zip files or doc files. There is a program called **foremost** that will try to recover various types of files based on their magic byte. If all that was lost in the rm -r is the metadata (filenames, modification times) then you should be able to recover some of the data. Although you'll have to then go through each file and rename it to something meaningful again. Good luck.

Comment: `Not sure what you mean by sd**a**1` OP wanted to emphasize the `a` letter by using bold formatting, which doesn't work properly when there are no surrounding spaces, unless you use the `<b>` HTML tag.